# Consumer records iterating continuously even the data is not getting

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

When I'm running my kafka code, consumer records are iterating continuously, even the producer records are also iterating.

It is looping like

```
[ Topic : 123456, Offset Id : 6, Partition : 0]
Consumed at :Wed Aug 17 10:59:24 IST 2016
10:59:24.359 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Committing offsets: {123456-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, metadata=''}} 
10:59:24.361 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group HYDTS001 committed offset 7 for partition 123456-0
10:59:24.460 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Committing offsets: {123456-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, metadata=''}} 
10:59:24.465 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group HYDTS001 committed offset 7 for partition 123456-0
10:59:24.561 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Committing offsets: {123456-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, metadata=''}} 
10:59:24.568 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group HYDTS001 committed offset 7 for partition 123456-0
10:59:24.662 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Committing offsets: {123456-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, metadata=''}} 
10:59:24.665 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group HYDTS001 committed offset 7 for partition 123456-0
10:59:24.763 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Committing offsets: {123456-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, metadata=''}} 
10:59:24.767 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group HYDTS001 committed offset 7 for partition 123456-0
```

How to trigger my consumer when the data comes to the topic only ?
Is it possible to do like that ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.